# iOS webView not loading mobile optimised page

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am submitting user details to a local server (POST Request) which then makes a call to payment gateway called ---->  [PayU](https://www.payu.in/index) .Now the response that I get from local server is a url which is a url of payU  and I am supposed to load it into webView.Now everything is fine till here.But the problem is that when I load this url in webView, it displays a Desktop optimised page and not a mobile optimised page.

I need to know a workaround if any from iOS end, so that I can load a mobile optimised page.For example will sending HTML form from my webView will help? Or anything else that can be done.

Here is how I load the webView currently.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlString];  //I get this url as a response of POST Request to a local server
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.paymentWebView loadRequest:request];
[self.paymentWebView scalesPageToFit];
```

Comment: A quick user agent switch in Chrome suggests that it does not have a mobile friendly site. Are you sure it supports mobile ?

Comment: Well if look in mobile payments tab ,it says they do  https://www.payu.in/whypayu

Answer (score 1):

**Swift**

The order matters. Switching the order works for me ^^

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!))
```